# Camel mail 2.13.0 searchterm: How to configure multiple from addresses?

Tags: apache-camel, jakarta-mail

I only have to consume mails from the mailbox which are from address x OR address y. How can i configure this in a camel uri?

I've only found the searchTerm configuration with 1 address(searchTerm.from=x)

Comment: A good idea can be to look at the unit tests source code and see how Camel tested this functionality itself in camel-mail

Comment: I've already looked at the code and the tests. Multiple searchTerms are combined with the AND operator, in my usecase I need an OR operator. So i would say it won't work with camel uri configuration or I've missed something. The only way I see is to build an custom searchtearm(searchTerm=#mysearchterm) which is unfortunatly not an option for us.

Comment: Okay but we do not support OR, so you have to build a custom term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segment your route using [Direct Component](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html.), it works like method call.

For example:

```
<route>
   <from uri="imap://admin@mymailserver_1"/>
   <to uri="direct:processMail"/>
</route>
 
<route>
   <from uri="imap://admin@mymailserver_2"/>
   <to uri="direct:processMail"/>
</route>

<route>
   <from uri="direct:processMail"/>
   <to uri="bean:MailService?method=process"/>
   <to uri="activemq:queue:mail.out"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's possible to setup 2 routes(one with searchTerm.from=x, the other with searchTerm.from=y), the questions is how to achieve the same behavior only with one route.

Comment: then try Content enricher http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Comment: The OR operator is not supported, so setting up 2 routes is the only working solution for us.