# apache camel mail - using custom searchTerm on From

Tags: apache, email, apache-camel

just a camel mail question.

does the FROM searchTerm support multiple email addresses?
I have a use case where multiple source email addresses can send.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    if (validateConfiguration()) {

        // Format the From Endpoint from Parameters.
        final String fromStr = String.format("%s://%s:%s?username=%s&password=%s"
                        + "&delete=%s&mail.pop3.forgettopheaders=%s"
                        + "&consumer.delay=%s" 
                        + "&consumer.initialDelay=%s"
                        + "&maxMessagesPerPoll=%s" 
                        + "&fetchSize=%s"
                        + "&mapMailMessage=false" 
                        + "&handleFailedMessage=true"
                        + "&skipFailedMessage=true"
                        + "&searchTerm.unseen=false"
                        + "&searchTerm.subject=%s"
                        + "&searchTerm.from=%s",
                protocol, host, port, username, password, mailDelete,
                pop3Headers, pollDelay, initialDelay, maxMessagesPerPoll,
                fetchSize, from);  //subject
        // + "&sortTerm=reverse,date"

        // Format the To Endpoint from Parameter(s).
        //final String toStr = String.format("%s", toEndpoint);
        final String toStr = String.format("%s", destination);      

        final String toStr = String.format("%s", preDestination);
```

from properties file load of route

subject=Exportfiles+V2+OMV+Attached
from=myemailaddress@something.com

is this acceptable?
from=myemailaddress@something.com,myotheraddress@somewhere.com

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766810/camel-mail-2-13-0-searchterm-how-to-configure-multiple-from-addresses

Comment: thanks soilworker, appreciated, yeah I found that article question too, I was hoping that multiple email addresses where supported, hoping not to create additional routes, but, it is what it is.  thanks! I take it there is no support for multiple addresses on the searchTerm.